# Yes or No in calculated fields instead of 1 or 0

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, boolean-field

Say, I have a SharePoint list with 2 columns, A and B. A contains a list with three items: one, two and three.

B is calculated yes/no field, where I use the formula `=If(A="two";TRUE;FALSE)`. This works fine.

So when I choose "two" the result in column B will be 1, and if I choose one or three, the result will be 0.

However, instead of seeing 1 or 0, I would like to see yes or no in column B.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up with your last question, while creating a new calculated column you need to select the **Yes/No** option for **The data type returned from this formula is** (below calculated formula box).

**Calculated Column Settings**:

[image]

**Update from comments**:

If this is not working for you then you can try `=If(A="two";"Yes";"No")`. But in this case you need to return it as "Single line of text" instead of "Yes/No".

Comment: Check the **The data type returned from this formula is** option highlighted in attached image. Here you need to choose the **Yes/No**.

Comment: I think i did it that way, but is stil see 1 or 2. ![See screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/cQrxn8L.jpg)

Comment: Strange. I am also doing the same thing and it is showing Yes or No values for me. If this is not working for you then you can try `=If(A="two";"Yes";"No")`. But in this case you need to return it as "Single line of text" instead of "Yes/No".

Comment: Yes! That works: =If(A="two";"Yes";"No") 
Thanks!